# Unity angle and position relative to direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vectormath

I'm trying to create a 'star' of vector points around a point with a constant angle between them and the original line between the source and the hit point (see pic) which I've done by creating new vectors with a small offset from the original:

[image]

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 3000))
    {

    Vector3 mousePos = hit.point;
    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hit.point, Color.yellow);

    Vector3[] explorePoints = new Vector3[6] {
                new Vector3 (hit.point.x - 1 , hit.point.y, hit.point.z + 1), // diag left
                new Vector3 (hit.point.x + 1 , hit.point.y, hit.point.z + 1), // diag right
                new Vector3 (hit.point.x - 1 , hit.point.y, hit.point.z), // left
                new Vector3 (hit.point.x + 1 , hit.point.y, hit.point.z), // right
                new Vector3 (hit.point.x - 1 , hit.point.y, hit.point.z - 1), // diag left back
                new Vector3 (hit.point.x + 1 , hit.point.y, hit.point.z - 1), // diag right back
    };

    for (int x = 0; x < explorePoints.Length; x++)
    {
        Debug.DrawLine(mousePos, explorePoints[x], Color.red);
    }

}
}
```

This works fine when the angle between the mouse approaches 0 or 180, but of course not at other angles:

[image]

I know I probably need the Quaternion class to apply the angle between the sphere and the mouse point to the direction vectors but can't quite figure it out e.g.

```
Quaternion q = Quaternion.FromToRotation(transform.position, mousePos);
for (int x = 0; x < explorePoints.Length; x++)
{
      Debug.DrawLine(mousePos, q * explorePoints[x], Color.red);
}
```

How do I keep the red lines at *n* angle to the yellow line at all times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```js
private void FixedUpdate()
  {
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 3000))
    {
      Vector3 mousePos = hit.point;
      Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hit.point, Color.yellow);
      Vector3 rayDir = transform.position - mousePos;
      Vector3[] explorePoints = new Vector3[6] {
        Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 45) * rayDir.normalized,
        Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90) * rayDir.normalized,
        Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 135) * rayDir.normalized,
        Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -45) * rayDir.normalized,
        Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -90) * rayDir.normalized,
        Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -135) * rayDir.normalized,
      };

      float starLength = 100;
      for (int x = 0; x < explorePoints.Length; x++)
      {
        // we want to use the vector as DIRECTION, not point, hence mousePos + explorePoints[x] (starLength is just the length of the red line)
        Debug.DrawLine(mousePos, mousePos + (explorePoints[x] * starLength), Color.red);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's not quite it, the angle isn't constant as you move the mouse point. I guess I need is to work out the direction (transform.position - hit.point), then create a vector which is at an angle to that direction, the bit I can't work out is how to keep that angle constant relative to the direction, rather than to world space. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try out the code? It rotate your Vector *by* 60 degree, not *to* 60 degree

Comment: Yes, and several variations of it. Try for yourself if you have time, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @Absinthe Ooh I think I see the problem. Check out my updated answer (note the comment inside the for loop)

Comment: Ahh, I didn't think to add the mousePos (and stupidly I forgot to mention my view was top down, so angles were around Y cord). Brilliant, thanks.